# gazebo failed on virtualbox with fuerte

Tags: ros, gazebo, virtualbox

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I use ubuntu 11.10 on virtualbox with 3D support.

I run

```
  roslaunch gazebo_worlds empty_world.launch
```

And when I click plane1_model's body and move cursor to gazebo world, gazebo exited.

[image: image description]

```
 OpenGL Warning: crPackDrawElements: trying to use bound but empty      elements buffer, ignoring.
 Qt has caught an exception thrown from an event handler. Throwing
 exceptions from an event handler is not supported in Qt. You must
 reimplement QApplication::notify() and catch all exceptions there.
 
 terminate called after throwing an instance of 'Ogre::InternalErrorException'
   what():  OGRE EXCEPTION(7:InternalErrorException): Vertex Buffer: Out of      memory in GLHardwareVertexBuffer::lock at      /tmp/buildd/ros-fuerte-visualization-common-1.8.4/debian/ros-fuerte-visualizati     on-common/opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/visualization_common/ogre/build/ogre_src_v     1-7-3/RenderSystems/GL/src/OgreGLHardwareVertexBuffer.cpp (line 126)
 /opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/simulator_gazebo/gazebo/scripts/gui: line 2:  3056 已     經終止            `rospack find gazebo`/gazebo/bin/gzclient -g `rospack find      gazebo`/lib/libgazebo_ros_paths_plugin.so
 [gazebo_gui-3] process has died [pid 3053, exit code 134, cmd      /opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/simulator_gazebo/gazebo/scripts/gui __name:=gazebo_gui      __log:=/home/sam/.ros/log/51435328-a021-11e1-9fcc-080027ef39bc/gazebo_gu     i-3.log].                                                                       
 log file:           /home/sam/.ros/log/51435328-a021-11e1-9fcc-080027ef39bc/gazebo_gui-3*.log
```

How to solve it?

Thank you~

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/34209/gazebo-failed-on-virtualbox-with-fuerte/) by [sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/189/sam/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2570 on 2012-05-17

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2012-05-17**:
Ogre often has trouble doing 3D graphics in a virtual machine. You may need to run it with a real driver (i.e. without virtualbox).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

From @joq Ogre often has trouble doing 3D graphics in a virtual machine. You may need to run it with a real driver (i.e. without virtualbox).

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2012-06-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I can confirm that I've used VB with gazebo. I did get a sigsegv, but that didn't happen every time. I was able to move the ground plane, and was even able to get the awesome [hector_quadrotor](http://ros.org/wiki/hector_quadrotor_gazebo) to run [nicely](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B9Gk5iW1PiEoT2I4MDhEeGVTZG8/preview)

Fuerte (from debs), Gazebo 1.6.14 (from debs), Virtualbox 4.1.20 (Precise guest, Snow Leopard host)

(as [hsu](http://answers.ros.org/users/91/hsu/) pointed out) apt-get install gnome-session-fallback, and login with classic (no effects)

There's also a notable performance benefit to using classic. Will update when done benchmarking.

---

Originally posted by [SL Remy](https://answers.ros.org/users/1001/sl-remy/) with karma: 2022 on 2012-09-06

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/189/sam/) on 2012-09-06**:
Is there any trick you have done? Thank you~

**Comment by [hsu](https://answers.ros.org/users/91/hsu/) on 2012-09-06**:
One thing I've learned is to turn off 3d effects in your ubuntu session, i.e. in precise, use gnome-session-fallback rather than unity 3d.

**Comment by [SL Remy](https://answers.ros.org/users/1001/sl-remy/) on 2012-09-07**:
Next target is stageros... https://code.ros.org/trac/ros-pkg/ticket/5552